# Name call in lagom service call?

Tags: scala, microservices, reactive, lagom

I am starting lagom and going through the doc and found this sample code :

```
named("hello").withCalls(
  namedCall("hello", sayHello)
)
```

And when implemented using REST, it says this call will have a path of /hello.

Now the question is , `/hello` refers to which hello, first "hello" in `named("hello")` or second hello in `namedCall("hello")` **and** does this both "hello" name should have to be same ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first `hello` is a name for the service. When a client looks up the service, it will use that name, passing it to the `ServiceLocator`, which, depending on its implementation, may translate it to a DNS lookup, or something similar.

The second `hello` refers to the `/hello` path.

They certainly do not have to be the same. This would also work:

```
named("hello").withCalls(
  namedCall("sayHello", sayHello)
)
```

In that case, the path would be `/sayHello`.